# NVIDIA QUADRO M4000 vGPU - ESXI 6.0.3 - GPU Passthrough

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, passthrough, pci

I'm trying to do a GPU passthrough to a vm (2008 64bit r2) ESXI 6.0.3. After the GPU passthrough and installing the NVidia drivers. I have disabled the VMWARE SVGA. Now in the device manager it shows only the Quadro M4000 enabled with the VMWARE Svga disable. My console view, and vnc is working fine. But I don't have any output on the back of the display ports. The display ports show me black.

To do this I did the following:

I did a GPU passthrough on the ESXI. THen installed the VM. passed VM the PCI card. Then installed the drivers in the VM. Connected a screen to port 1 and ran the Nvidia Control panel. From the control panel in the System Topology I exported the EDID. Then loaded the edid of the connected port. It showed me the TV icon on the connected port in the GUI. Then I made the External screen as my main display. Disabled the VMWARE SVGA. After this I restarted the VM. MY VM console screen is working, VNC is working fine and in the device manager I can see VMWARE Svga to be disabled with Nvidia card enabled. Now if I put a screen on the display ports it shows me black.

Is this normal. Is the GPU passthrough done properly.

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re doing this. PCI-passthrough in VMware is almost never worthwhile. What is the purpose of this science experiment?

Comment: Its required by one of the software vendors who needs some more gpu power to run his software

Comment: Is this on a server? What type of server hardware is in use? Should this be a baremetal solution?

Comment: its a supported configuration from nVidia perspective - what screen are you putting 'on the display ports' the ports are virtualized inside the VM - if your VM PCI device lists nVidia it's working

Comment: Thanks @Sum. So I can assume the Display ports if connected to the screens would be blank. correct ?

Comment: @ewwhite: Its on DL380 Gen9. Its a baremetal ofcourse. ESXI 6.0.3

Comment: yes the physical display ports are a separate bus, the virtual PCI bus inside VM is what matters here. it does beg the question 'why not just use the bare metal?' unless you have multiple VM's with different OSes etc.